# Delphi Enumerated types in REST Server

Tags: delphi, rest, enums, datasnap

I have a Delphi XE5 (Update 2) program created using the IDE's standard 'File | New | Other | DataSnap Server| DataSnap REST Application' Wizard.

I cannot seem to get enumerated types to work when used as a parameter of a server method. All other server methods work such as those that take other classes as parameters, strings etc. When I try to call the method that has an enum parameter from a web browser, I get the error message `'Project Project1.exe raised exception class TDBXError with message 'TServerMethods1.EnumString method not found in the server method list'`.

Here's my basic test code:

```
type
{$METHODINFO ON}
  TMyEnum=(meOne, meTwo);

  TServerMethods1 = class(TDataModule)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function EchoString(Value: string): string;
    function ReverseString(Value: string): string;
    function EnumString(const AEnum: TMyEnum): string;
  end;
{$METHODINFO OFF}
```

However, what is weird is that I can get enumerated types to work if they are contained within another class and then this class is passed a parameter to my method. If I change the enum parameter to be an integer, then this work, but I don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using enumerations is not supported as method arguments. If Datasnap finds an argument type on a method that it doesn't support it will act as if the method doesn't exist, which causes the error you see.

For a list of supported argument types, look at the TDSServerClass documentation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Datasnap.DSServer.TDSServerClass

Comment: Strange that enums work in properties of classes though but not method paramters. I can live with this though.Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you passing the class to the method? What is the method signature? Are you using GET or another http verb? Depending on how you do it, when you pass an object to a method, it gets passed through a deserializer first and the deserializer may support enums even though the Datasnap router doesn't.